# Impute motives to somebody

Tags: usage

What is the meaning of the following sentence

> You were not justified in **imputing motives** to him.

Is this an idiom? I looked up its meaning but didn't find anything.(no further context can be provided as it is just an example sentence in my book)

Comment: What book? Is it from a dictionary or grammar book? If so, which word or grammatical concept was being explained?

Answer (score 1):

To [impute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impute) a motive to someone is to assume or conclude that the person had that motive. The term is generally used when the person assigning the motive has no evidence, or only limited evidence, that the motive is accurate. The term "impute" is often used with a somewhat negative connotation, implying that a person has assumed a  motive unjustifiably, where other possibilities exist. The term "impute" is particularly likely to be used  when the motive under discussion is itself negative. For example

> You should not impute greed to him, he may have acted out of misplaced caution.

The word "impute" can also be used where the motive being assigned or assumed is neutral or positive, but is not as common in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's a good idea to look up the etymology (root origin) of a word to better comprehend it. Impute is related to compute. Both of their putes come from Latin. In whole, impute is from Latin imputare, which breaks down to in (into) and putare (to trim, clean, prune, settle up [an account].("Settle up" means to pay a debt or set/make the numbers or matters correct/fair.) So a computer is something that computes; a machine "with settling up numbers correct[ly]." Which brings us back to "impute wrong motive." Remember, in + putare/into + settling up. Tricky to decode, but the meaning is that you're "putting into" [a person, in this case] your own "settling up" [of them]. Or, you're imposing your own calculations and those "settle up" (calculate) a wrong/bad motive. The mistake inherent in the action of imputing is that YOU are PUTTING IN something that may not be valid. To impute wrong motive is to deduce/calculate/"settle up" that someone did something for a stinky reason (and therefore they must be a stinky person). Very often we simply don't have enough information to know why people do things. It is almost always a mistake to impute wrong motive, because there usually was was none.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! While your answer is quite informative, most of the information is not relevant for the average English learner. David Siegel's answer already provides a simpler (and probably clearer) explanation, and he also provides a very useful link to a dictionary definition.